# Writing curl output to a shell variable. CURL output is being condensed to 1 line. Newline missing?

Tags: bash, curl, newline, sh

I am trying to retrieve the contents of a .html file into a variable using the following:

```
data=$(curl --silent "$url");
```

If I echo $data I get the follwing:

```
 </html>of_Hg_sensor_2 -23.29362<br/>eta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"></meta></head>
```

It appears that it's never starting a new line and simply keeps dumping each successive line over the last.

If I run the same 'curl --silent "$url"' in a shell or redirect output to a file everything looks fine.  I've tried running in sh and bash.

I know I could simply retrieve the file but I'd like to avoid a file writes as this will be a heavily repeated process.

I've got to be missing something simple/stupid?

Comment: Use quotes: `echo "$data"`

Comment: Answer by Anubhava is right. To learn more, check [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator).

Comment: "$data" got it.  Thanks.  Reading wiki link next.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "$data"
```

Without the double quotes, the newlines are converted to spaces.